# GWT/AppEngine: Designing RequestFactory workflow for better exception handling

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

Let's look at an usual RequestFactory server side code trying to find a student.

```
Student s = null;
try{
    ....
    s = pm.findStudent(....)
    ....
}catch(Exception e){
    ....
}finally{
    pm.close();
}
return s;
```

Here if there is an exception there is a chance that 's' remains null. But it will be difficult for the client side code to determine whether there was an exception or whether the student was not found. So instead if I remove the exception block:

```
Student s = null;
try{
    ....
    s = pm.findStudent(....)
    ....
}finally{
    pm.close();
}
return s;
```

I will be able to handle the exception on the client side with RequestFactory's onFaliure. This will help me easily take the necessary action for both cases i.e. if the student is not found v/s there is an exception.

I wish to understand if this is the right way, potential pitfalls, or is there a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think in terms of requests (method name and arguments) and responses (return type).

If you want to return an object and/or an error, then use a `ValueProxy` with two properties, e.g.

```
@ProxyFor(FindStudentResponse.class)
interface FindStudentResponseProxy extends ValueProxy {
  StudentProxy getStudent();
  FindError getError();
}
```

where `FindError` would be an enum.

Comment: Yes that is an alternative I am aware of. My query is more towards whether the approach of skipping exception handling on server side and handling it on the client side, to help us differentiate between successful and unsuccessful calls, is a good one or not. Potential pitfalls?

Comment: It's not. One issue is how to communicate the type of failure to the client; you'll likely define your own _protocol_ within the `ServerFailure` message. RF's `onFailure` is not the same as GWT-RPC's `onFailure`.